# DB2: Working with concurrent DDL operations

Tags: sql, concurrency, db2, ddl

We are working on a data warehouse using IBM DB2 and we wanted to load data by partition exchange. That means we prepare a temporary table with the data we want to load into the target table and then use that entire table as a data partition in the target table. If there was previous data we just discard the old partition.

Basically you just do "ALTER TABLE target_table ATTACH PARTITION pname [starting and ending clauses] FROM temp_table".

It works wonderfully, but only for one operation at a time. If we do multiple loads in parallel or try to attach multiple partitions to the same table it's raining deadlock errors from the database.

From what I understand, the problem isn't necessarily with parallel access to the target table itself (locking it changes nothing), but accesses to system catalog tables in the background.

I have combed through the DB2 documentation but the only reference to the topic of concurrent DDL statements I found at all was to avoid doing them. The answer to this question, can't be to simply not attempt it?

Does anyone know a way to deal with this problem?

I tried to have a global, single synchronization table to lock if you want to attach any partitions, but it didn't help either. Either I'm missing something (implicit commits somewhere?) or some of the data catalog updates even happen asynchronously, which makes the whole problem much worse. If that is the case, is there are any chance at all to query if the attach is safe to perform at any given moment?

Comment: Do you have nonpartitioned-indexes on the partitioned table? (this always causes heartaches after attach partition ). For the unattached tables , ensure they have dedicated tablespaces (not shared with any other tables) for data, indexes, long. Loading into such tables should not cause any concurrency trouble. Ensure that the transaction that performs the attach has only a single DDL (the alter...attach) followed by a COMMIT. At worst, you can serialise the attach actions.

Comment: Maybe you can ask this question at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mao Creating the temporary table never posed a problem yet. But moving them to their own tablespace might be a good idea.

"How" would I go about serializing the attach actions? That's what I attempted by locking a global synchronization table. The attach operation is fast, so I'm not worried about creating bottlenecks.

Comment: Attaching a data partition places a table into Set Integrity Pending state. This state is visible with the statement like `SELECT 1 FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME) = ('TABLE_SCHEMA', 'TABLE_NAME') AND STATUS = 'C'` for this partitioned table. So, just check it before an attempt to attach a new data partition. Don't forget to commit after ATTACH immediately to make this status be visible as soon as possible. But if you really have many concurrent session attaching partitions quickly, this might not help either, and you really should use some external object for synchronization...

Comment: You may also add the `WITH UR` clause to the query above to check for uncommitted `ATTACH` running on this table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mark. I manually do "SET IMMEDIATE CHECKED" on the tables after attaching, so I don't know how long they are in that state. When I lock the table, do the attach and the integrity check and then commit, I thought it should be a safe transaction. It didn't help though.
How would I go about using an external object for synchronization? At this point I'm afraid that route is going to be unavoidable

Comment: External object helps you to avoid deadlock (if you don't mess it up with lock timeout). The transaction design must be: lock this object, attach, set integrity, commit. You don't get any deadlocks between whatever number of such tasks. Only lock timeouts may happen, if you configured lock timeout too short in your session.